# Semantic UI Form Validation RegEx will not match a mm/dd/yyyy date

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, semantic-ui

I'm trying to validate a text input for a text box to only allow mm/dd/yyyy input. The regex seems to be valid for what I'm trying to match based on regex tester.

What is causing it to fail, and how can I go about fixing it?

RegEx: `(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d`

Regex Test: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=93828

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tL5xx6m9/2/

Snippet:

```js
$('.ui.form').form({
  inline: true,
  fields: {
    dateInput: {
      identifier: 'dateInput',
      rules: [{
        type: "regExp[/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/]",
        prompt: "Please select a valid mm/dd/yyyy date"
      }]
    },
    timeInput: {
      identifier: 'timeInput',
      rules: [{
        type: "regExp[/^(OFF)|([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])? [APap][mM]$/]",
        prompt: "Please select a valid hh:mm AM/PM time"
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>


<form class="ui form attached fluid segment">
  <div class="field">
    <input name="dateInput" value="01/15/2015" type="text" placeholder="Entry Date">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input name="timeInput" class="field-custom" value="5:30 PM" type="text" id="" placeholder="Entry Time">
  </div>
  <button class="ui teal button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why not just use a date input? seems more semantic than off-side JS...

Comment: I am using a date input, however it still allows invalid input such as a single number, or 5/1, or 5/55/555555 ...etc I want to cleanly tie the validation for that field into the rest of the validation for my form, which is why I am trying to use a regex to validate this input field. I have edited my question to also include a working regex example.

Comment: all the inputs in your code, like `name="dateInput"` seem to use a `type=text`, not date...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I am using the JQuery datepicker instead of the HTML5 one, so the type of the input needs to be that of "text" and not "date". Perhaps I'm just using the wrong tools for the job?

Comment: Goran gave a great answer below, you should accept it as correct.

Comment: @neokio Thanks for noticing, I may have overlooked this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your regex expression is part of a javascript string, any backslashes need to be escaped by using a double backslash. So `\d` becomes `\\d`.

Also, use the start of string `^` and end of string `$` markers to prevent matches from larger strings, such as `01/15/20155`, being successful.

**Result:**

```
type: "regExp[/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$/]",
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.ui.form').form({
  inline: true,
  fields: {
    dateInput: {
      identifier: 'dateInput',
      rules: [{
        type: "regExp[/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$/]",
        prompt: "Please select a valid mm/dd/yyyy date"
      }]
    },
    timeInput: {
      identifier: 'timeInput',
      rules: [{
        type: "regExp[/^(OFF)|([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])? [APap][mM]$/]",
        prompt: "Please select a valid hh:mm AM/PM time"
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>


<form class="ui form attached fluid segment">
  <div class="field">
    <input name="dateInput" value="01/15/2015" type="text" placeholder="Entry Date">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input name="timeInput" class="field-custom" value="5:30 PM" type="text" id="" placeholder="Entry Time">
  </div>
  <button class="ui teal button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```